# Current ruby and rails resources (2010)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can you great and knowledgable programmers please point me to some current and updated Ruby/Rails blogs/sites? I am also looking for an active forum for lively discussions on ruby/rails.

I already tried to google for them but as I [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794270/is-ruby-on-rails-or-at-least-the-community-dying-closed) on SO, many of the links on google seem to be to sites that are no longer updated.

Comment: have you tried my recommendation from your previous question - http://rubyflow.com? The site aggregates links to many Ruby/Rails blogs. So after a week or so you will have nice set of RoR blogs/resources/active people that you can follow directly if you like.

Comment: Ironically, RubyFlow is, at the time of writing, down, and [not just for me](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/rubyflow.com)!

Comment: @pawien yes, rubyflow (when it was up) looked like a great resource. i was hoping to find a few more since my question was closed :( but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: funny, isn't it? I use rubyflow every day and when I send link it's down. OMG, those computers... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New website that started for rails developers: http://railsdeveloper.com/

Great blogs are: http://railstips.org/, http://railstutorial.org/

mislav created a cool tool at GoGaRuCo called explain ruby: http://explainruby.net/

screencasts: http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following to be very useful:

Online forum: **railsforum**

IRC (instant answers): irc://irc.freenode.net/#rubyonrails

Video tutorials: **railscasts**

If you can't watch online videos: asciicasts

Answer (score 0):

Rails Community [page](http://rubyonrails.org/community) would be a nice start point for you.

Comment: Yes, that page has links for both Planet Ruby on Rails and the Ruby on Rails Talk mailing lists, which are the first two resources that I thought of when I saw this question.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and for asking questions and lively discussions I use SO (it is a great site, if you still don't use it, you should give it a try!)

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby blog aggregators, there are [ruby-blogs.com](http://www.ruby-blogs.com) and rubycorner.com.