# Is Ruby on Rails dying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am interested in learning Ruby/RoR, but it seems to have lost the popularity it had a few short years ago, and from what I've read, few webhosts support it. Is it on its way out?

Comment: It's not dead, it's resting. Impossible to answer without inciting a highly subjective flamewar (in other words, your question is "Do you think RoR is worth learning?"), voting to close as such.

Comment: Not interested in a flameware, really. Just an honest discussion.

Comment: @Tim76: In that case, it should be a community wiki, at best.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: CW is now a moderator-only option :/

Comment: Some very good webhosts are up just for serving Rails such as http://www.heroku.com and http://www.engineyard.com. And Rails 3.0 just came out and it's wonderful!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794270/is-ruby-on-rails-or-at-least-the-community-dying

Comment: How many different webhosts do you need to support it?  Are you planning to run your app on 100 different hosts?

Comment: Tim76: Unfortunately, "This is not a discussion board".

Comment: @Tim76: re "interested in a discussion" - refer FAQ: "This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!" http://stackoverflow.com/faq (Maybe try programmers.stackexchange.com - your question might be a better fit there)

Answer (score 2):

Still seems to be growing in the U.S., it's just not as hyped as it was. [See job stats from indeed](http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=ruby+on+rails&l=)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say it's on its way out, it just lost some of the hype--which isn't a bad thing.

I don't think there has ever been a ridiculous amount of hosting support; but there are a few,  there's a list of hosts that provide rails support at http://www.rubyonrailswebhost.com/

Answer (score 1):

No.

I find more and more nice little startups that are using it (my favorite recent finds: toggl.com and zencoder.com).  There are also many good web hosts, but in my experience the best of them is heroku.com.

If you're interested in learning it, find a local user group.  There's always people there willing to share their interest.

Answer (score 0):

I worked for some start-ups and all of them used Ruby on Rails.

Comment: That was the case I was hearing locally abou 1.5 - 2 years ago. I don't think many of those start-ups still exist (though I don't think RoR had anything to do with that though their failure would take some RoR players off the market). How is it where you are? Did they do better?

Comment: RoR is still hot but it is not suitable for any type of start-up. It is known for RoR world that people usually say "We can do everything with RoR, why using Java". You should search for "programmers" that will use RoR not the RoR developers!